# How to setup the border of an element in my case

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div hack for my table.

I want to place a div in a table cell that block the cell bottom border and create a effect that the cell is extended below.

HTML

```
<table cellspacing="15">
    <tr>
       <td>123</td><td>123 <div class="block"></div></td><td>123</td><td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>123</td><td>123</td><td>123</td><td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>123</td><td>123</td><td>123</td><td>123</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

css

```
td {
    position:relative;
    border:solid 1px red;
    padding:0;
}

.block {
    background-color: white;
    border-left:solid 1px red;
    border-right:solid 1px red;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:10px;
    top:10px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tfjm7L5y/

For some reason, the border left and border right in my `.block` div doesn't line up with the table cell right/left border. Is there something I am missing here? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `left` property to account for the misalignment. The element  `.block <div>` is a child of its parent, and so its border is also contained within the parent `<td>` space. That's why your `.block <div>` doesn't align properly to the furthest outside border on the `<td>`. The difference should be the size of the parent `<td>` border (1px).

```
.block {
    background-color: white;
    border-left:solid 1px red;
    border-right:solid 1px red;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:10px;
    top:10px;
    left: -1px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tfjm7L5y/1/